# replacing ceiling fixture

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling

I just moved into 1920's house and would like to install a chandelier. There are 3 wires tied together and one separate. They are not color coded. All are in some sort of fabric insulation and pretty thick. Which one I connect to black and which to a white from my fixture?

Comment: Pictures of the inside of the switch box and the ceiling light box would be helpful.

Comment: With the old lamp still attached.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both boxes?

Comment: Without photos, best "guess" is your tied wires are your neutral wire (aka white) and the singe is your switched hot from the switch (aka black).

Comment: Also note that a box with a regular fixture on it might not be rated for the weight of a chandelier or a ceiling fan.  Those require special boxes/mounting.